# We are allowed to erase the pair of numbers $(a, b)$ from the board and replace it with one of the following pairs: $(b, a), (a − b, b), (a + b, b)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

> A pair of integers are written on a blackboard. At each step, we are allowed to erase the pair of numbers $(a, b)$ from the board and replace it with one of the following pairs: $(b, a), (a − b, b), (a + b, b)$. If we start with $(2022, 315)$ written on the blackboard, then can we eventually have the pair
> (a) $(30, 45)$,
> (b) $(222, 15)$?

---

Note that $\gcd(2022,315) = 3$, $\gcd(30,45) = 15$ and $\gcd(222,15) = 3$.

By Bezout's identity, any number which is a multiple of $3$ can be written in the form $2022x+315y$ for some integers $x$ and $y$.

Note that each of the numbers $30,45,222,15$ are divisible by $3$.

Can anyone provide some hints on how to proceed?

---

Source: Homework Assignment problems.

Comment: Please edit to include the source of this problem.  Questions involving the current year often appear in tests and contests.

Comment: Your argument effectively is that $\gcd(a,b)$ divides $\gcd(a+b,b)$, which, while true, is too weak.  In fact, $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a+b,b)$.  Use that to strengthen your argument.

Comment: To continue in that spirit, it should be obvious that one of those two pairs can not be reached.  The other needs more thinking.

Comment: Suppose that you have two numbers, $a,b$, at least one of which is not a multiple of $n$.  Is it possible that the result of a transformation will be two numbers, both of which are multiples of $n$?

Comment: Also, compare the allowable transformations, with the mechanics of the Euclidean Algorithm, which is used to produce the gcd.

Comment: Hint: the gcd of a tuple is *invariant* under each operation, and each operation is *invertible*, so if there are paths from $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ to a common point then there are paths to each other. Choose the common point to be $(g,0)$ where $g$ is their common gcd.

Comment: Not an answer, but I built this little [interactive Desmos notebook](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8zwq7ajboz) to get a feel for the transformations. You can drag the point $(a, b)$ around on the integer lattice and watch in real time where the three transformed points land. (I called them $S$, $P$, and $M$ for “switch”, “plus”, and “minus”, respectively.) If you click on the folder called “Guidelines”, you toggle a semicircle and line of reflection to further elucidate the geometry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the hints provided in the comments above, I will try to write a solution.

Since $\gcd (30,45) \neq \gcd(2022,315)$, the pair $(30,45)$ cannot be obtained using the given operations.

Next,

$(2022,315) \to (132,315) \to (315,132) \to (132,51) \to (51,30) \to (30,21) \to (21,9) \to (9,3)$

$ \to (12,3) \to (15,12) \to (12,15) \to (222,15).$

Hence we can reach the pair $(222,15)$ from $(2022,315)$ using the given operations.

Comment: If you gave a convincing argument why $\gcd (30,45) \neq \gcd(2022,315)$ implies you can't get to $(30,45),$ you wouldn't need to demonstrate how to get to $(222,15)$ (though it might be instructive nevertheless). Of course the answer was already given in a comment.